# How can I use CreateProcess method to refer to other 'ini' file to start 'exe' program?

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to execute 'ClientProc.exe'. This program uses 'SA_Client.ini' file from a same directory as a reference.

I'm using CreateProcess method to execute the .exe program as belows.

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

// set the size of the structures
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
LPCSTR lpApplicationName = "C:\\projects\\Client\\ClientProc.exe";
LPSTR cmd = (char*)"./";
if (!CreateProcess(lpApplicationName,   // the path
    cmd,            // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi             // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure (removed extra parentheses)
))
{
    printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}

// Wait until child process exits.
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

// Close process and thread handles. 
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make CreateProcess to refer to the 'ini' file even though the file exists in the same directory.
I've checked Microsoft document or other StackOverflow comments but couldn't find anything useful.

Does anyone know how to do it?
Thank you in advance!

--Edit--
I've also tried setting the lpCurrentDirectory parameter where ini file exists.

```
CreateProcess(lpApplicationName,   // the path
        NULL,           // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        "C:\\projects\\Client",           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi             // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure (removed extra parentheses)
    )
```

Then, I've got an error 267 which stands for 'ERROR_DIRECTORY'. I'm sure that the file exists in the directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean? CreateProcess doesn't care about your ini files

Comment: @user253751 Exactly.. I don't even know whether using CreateProcess is a right choice then since I want 'ClientProc.exe' to refer to 'ini' file in the same directory. Do you have any suggestions in this case?

Comment: Well you need to look at ClientProc.exe and look at how ClientProc.exe finds the ini file. CreateProcess has nothing to do with it. Analogy: You are asking how to make your mouse find the ini file when you double-click on ClientProc.exe.

Comment: @user253751 I see your point. I can normally refer to a different file upon a double clicking if the file exists in the same directory though. CreateProcess doesn't seem to have such option and need to find one.

Comment: How do you refer to a different file upon a double-clicking?

Comment: I don't know how and why it works if you ask me. But a file is referred as long as it exists in the same directory with the .exe file.

Comment: @AlexF Command line options don't exist for 'ClientProc.exe'.

Comment: How do you refer to a different file upon a double-clicking?

Comment: @AlexF It'd be great if you can take a look at the 'edited' post. Do you have any ideas on this?

Comment: try using `CreateProcess(NULL, lpApplicationName, ...`

Comment: @MarcStroebel lpApplicationName is the very first parameter. I get a compiler error with your command.

Comment: *How do you refer to a different file upon a double-clicking?*